# how to get a specific data by using a string argument?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using this method to get the price of all item that has a category name value bt it is not showing anything...

```
public long getcostmain(String xyz)throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "=" + xyz, null, null, null, null);
          long cost = 0;
             for(c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                 cost = cost + c.getLong(3);
             }

                return cost;
    }
```

Comment: Not showing in the sense, is there any problem any exception, explain clearly

Comment: problem is when i use this method and showing this long value by converting to first string then showing through edittext it shows a value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you query data from your database, you need to change your code to following:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "='" + xyz +"'", null, null, null, null);
```

You need to put **'** mark around your xyz string.

Comment: @scripter..If his answer helps you don't forgot to accept this as answer by marking check mark beside the answer.